# JavaScript Newbie: Undefined Appears at Top of Generated Text File

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, undefined, streamwriter

JavaScript newbie here. I am trying to generate a csv text file with 10 lines of two randomly generated numbers separated by commas. I've gotten very close, except 'undefined' is printed write before the loop commences. I managed to complete this task in Python with ease, which I am more familiar with. If someone could kindly help me out, then I would be much appreciative.

Thanks,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('data.csv', {flags: 'a'});

function generateCSV(){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        var min = 1;
        var max = 25;
        var A = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        var B = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        logger.write("" + A + "," + B + "\n");
    }
}


fs. writeFile('data.csv', generateCSV(), function (err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
});

RESULTS:
undefined6,11
22,13
10,19
21,19
12,21
8,17
11,6
22,6
15,18
9,16
```

Comment: I've tried deleting the old csv and running again and get the same results. When I delete the append portion then I get a truncated 'undefined' which appears like 'undefi'

Comment: you're passing the return value of `generateCSV()` to the last call to `writeFile()`.  The function has no `return` statement. You don't really need that call.

Comment: Call `generateCSV()` and then close the `logger` stream.

Comment: Oh I got it! Thanks to Pointy. I commented out the fs.writeFile at the bottom, called generateCSV() on it's own, and set the parameter to write instead of append. Now it works the way I wanted. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call generateCSV and then close the logger, you can remove all this:

```
fs. writeFile('data.csv', generateCSV(), function (err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
});
```

and just use

```
generateCSV()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I got it to work like this.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('data.csv', {flags: 'w'});

function generateCSV(){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        var min = 1;
        var max = 25;
        var A = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        var B = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        logger.write("" + A + "," + B + "\n");
    }
}

generateCSV();


//fs. writeFile('data.csv', generateCSV(), function (err){
//  if (err) throw err;
//  console.log('Saved!');
//});
```